# re no puedo localizar un grupo determinado de caracteres

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Tengo el siguiente problema con re en python.

Como parte de un ejercicio debo convertir una lista de diccionarios a string y posteriormente utilizando el modulo re.

Reconstruir la lista:

este es el codigo re que utilizo:

```
re.compile('[({a-z:a-z})]')
```

Este es el ejercicio completo:

```
import re
lista = [{"hola":"como"},{"estas":"cuko"}] #Lista original
lista2 = str(lista)
lista3 = []

p = re.compile('[({a-z:a-z})]') #debe buscar el patron {palabra:palabra}
if p.match(lista2):
    lista3.append(p)
print(p)
```

pero no funciona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sí entendi bien tu posteo, voy a plantear una posible solución utilizando `json.dumps`, `findall` y `join`

1) Convertir **lista** en `string` :

```
import json
result = json.dumps(lista) 
print(result)
```

output:

```
'[{"hola": "como"}, {"estas": "cuko"}]'
```

2) Buscamos solo letras y el espacio por cada palabra:

```
re.findall(r"([a-z A-Z])",result)
```

output:

```
['h',
 'o',
 'l',
 'a',
 ' ',
 'c',
 'o',
 'm',
 'o',
 ' ',
 'e',
 's',
 't',
 'a',
 's',
 ' ',
 'c',
 'u',
 'k',
 'o']
```

3) Finalmente usamos `join`: (*método que toma todos los elementos en un iterable para crear una cadena*):

```
"".join(re.findall(r"([a-z A-Z])",result))
```

output:

```
'hola como estas cuko'
```